# Python equivalent of sum() using xor()

Tags: python, sum, xor

I like the Python sum function :

```
>>> z = [1] * 11
>>> zsum = sum(z)
>>> zsum == 11
True
```

I want the same functionality with using xor (^) not add (+). I want to use map. But I can not work out how to do this. Any hints?

I am not satisfied with this :

```
def xor(l):
    r = 0
    for v in l: r ^= v
    return v
```

I want a 1 liner using map. Hints?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
zxor = reduce(lambda a, b: a ^ b, z, 0)

import operator
zxor = reduce(operator.xor, z, 0)
```

Comment: btw. you don't need to pass the 0. just `reduce(operator.xor, z)` is enough, provided z is not empty. With zero it gives 0 xor z[0] xor z[1]..., without it gives z[0] xor z[1] xor z[2]...
Also, reduce is in functools

Answer (score 5):

Note that starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), we can use and update a variable within a list comprehension and thus reduce a list to the xor of its elements:

```
zxor = 0
[zxor := zxor ^ x for x in [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
# zxor = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

### A one-liner

```py
eval( '^'.join( str(n) for n in nums ) )
```

`nums`: an array of int

### Explanation

Let's say `nums = [7,2,1,8,3,1]`

`'^'.join( [ str(n) for n in nums ] )` would join `nums` as follow:

> `"7^2^1^8^3^1"`

`eval("7^2^1^8^3^1")` would result as `14`, which is the [XOR sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284337/what-is-an-xor-sum) of `nums`.