# What is an XOR sum?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, xor

I am not sure of the precise definition of this term.

I know that a bitwise XOR operation is going bit by bit and taking the XOR of corresponding bits position wise. Is this result termed the 'XOR sum'? If not, what is an XOR sum, and how do you use XOR to implement this addition?

Comment: Read about [checksums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum).

Comment: `xorsum = A xor B xor C xor .... xor N`

Comment: Could you give a reference to this term? Where have you foud it? XOR works as a bitwise adder which disregards the carry.

Comment: The term comes from a cryptography problem assignment: Write a function that takes two equal-length buffers and produces
their XOR sum. I do not want an answer or an explanation of the question, just the definition of XOR sum in this (or any) context.

Comment: In finite field arithmetic with mod 2, XOR equals to a sum. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In a bit wise XOR operation:

```
a   b   a^b
-----------
0   0    0
0   1    1
1   0    1
1   1    0
```

XOR sum refers to successive XOR operations on integers.
Suppose you have numbers from `1` to `N` and you have to find their XOR sum, then for `N = 6`, XOR sum will be `1^2^3^4^5^6 = 7`.

```
1 = 001,  2 = 010,   3 = 011,   4 = 100,   5 = 101,   6 = 110  

 1^2          = 1^2  = 001^010 = 011 = 3  
(1^2)^3       = 3^3  = 011^011 = 000 = 0
(1^2^3)^4     = 0^4  = 000^100 = 100 = 4
(1^2^3^4)^5   = 4^5  = 100^101 = 001 = 1
(1^2^3^4^5)^6 = 1^6  = 001^110 = 111 = 7 --> XOR sum
```

---

### Tips:

Remember these basic rules of XOR operation while doing XOR sum:

- `0^a = a` (e.g. `0^3 = 3`)
- `a^a = 0` (e.g. `3^3 = 0`)
- XOR operations are cumutative (swapping doesn't matter). `a^b` = `b^a`
- XOR operations are assosiative (grouping doesn't matter). `(a^b^c)` = `(a^b)^c` = `a^(b^c)`

Examples with application of above rules:

- `1^2^1 = (1^1)^2 = 0^2 = 2`
- `(1^2^1) ^ (1^2) = (1^2)^(1^2) ^ 1 = 0^1 = 1`

Hope this will help.